# retrieving input from an array

Tags: ruby, xml, arrays

I have my system class

```
class System
    @os
    @base
    @number
    def setOs(newos)
        @os = newos
    end
    def getOs()
        return @os
    end
    def setBase(newbase)
        @base = newbase
    end
    def getBase()
        return @base
    end
    def setSystemNumber(newnumber)
        @number = newnumber
    end
    def getSystemNumber()
        return @number
    end
end
```

and I have my method to add multiple instances of system to an array

```
def readXMLSystems

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("/Users/lewisardern/Documents/Security-Simulator/lib/xml/boxesconfig.xml"))
    # puts doc
    systeminstance = ""
    systemArray = []

    doc.search('//systems/system').each do |system|
        systeminstance = System. new 
        number = system.at('@number').text
        systeminstance.setSystemNumber number
        os = system.at('@os').text
        systeminstance.setOs os
        base = system.at('@basebox').text
        systeminstance.setBase base

        systemArray.insert(systeminstance)
    end

    return systemArray
end
```

and i call that method by

```
sys = readXMLSystems
puts sys
```

how come i can't read the XML code? 
if i write inside the loop it spits out

```
puts systeminstance.getSystemNumber #retrieves input

1
2
3
```

I want to be able to have multiple systems inside this array but it doesn't seem to be returning... where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
systemArray.push(systeminstance) # or systemArray << systeminstance
```

instead of

```
systemArray.insert(systeminstance)
```

Also please, take a look at the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Edit: Just to show how the same can be achieved in a Ruby style way (not tested). As you can see I removed more than the 80% of the code. A code like this is more OOP, functional, clean  and will lend you to have much less bugs.

```
System = Struct.new(:os, :base, :number)

def read_systems_xml
    filename = "/Users/lewisardern/Documents/Security-Simulator/lib/xml/boxesconfig.xml"
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(filename))

    doc.search('//systems/system').map do |system|
        System.new(
          system.at('@os').text, 
          system.at('@basebox').text, 
          system.at('@number').text)
    end
end
```

Comment: that worked, jesus christ seems i have a lot to learn. - using your method instead much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, and you can do it! PS.: A former C# developer.

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, this is pretty non-idiomatic Ruby

```
def setOs(newos)
    @os = newos
end
def getOs()
    return @os
end
```

You don't have to hand-write getters/setters. And explicit `return` calls are infrequently needed.

This should be written using the `attr_accessor` macro

```
class System
  attr_accessor :os
end
```

If you want to write it by hand

```
class System

  def os
    @os
  end

  def os= os
    @os = os
  end

end
```

Don't bring idioms from your previous teachings to new languages you're learning.

Anyway, this is broken. There's no such method as `Array#insert`

```
systemArray.insert(systeminstance)
```

Correct this to

```
systemArray << systeminstance
```

---

Other griefs

- Ruby is dynamically typed, so don't add type names to your variables: `systemArray` or `systeminstance` should be called `systems` and `system` respectively.
- Ruby doesn't use camelCase: even if `systemArray` was an appropriate variable name, it would be `system_array`. Same goes for method names. `setSystemName` should be `system_name=`